# How to publish local ODBC data source to azure data factory?

Tags: ssis, odbc, azure-data-factory

We have  some SSIS packages that run on azure data factory. We have Azure SQL Server connections that use Azure AD User authentication. Due to some internal requests we need to switch to Service Principal auth. With creating my l"ocal ODBC data provider" I am able to connect to database. But how do I publish this local "User DSN" to data factory? Because right now when I publish my project the connection fails with the following error given.

" An error occurred with the following error message: "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: Could you please provide me the process which you have followed?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula it didnt work so i didnt use that method